# Fastest way to access values in a array

Tags: php

I have a PHP array like this, it contains search results based on a specific query.

```
Array
(
[2] => Array
    (
        [status] => 0
        [item] => something
        [catagory] => something
    )

[23] => Array
    (
        [status] => 1
        [item] => something
        [catagory] => something
    )

[24] => Array
    (
        [status] => 1
        [item] => something
        [catagory] => something
    )
)
```

I have two ways to access data if I need to access data in a specific array.

```
foreach($contents as $content => $data){
    if($content == '23'){
          $result = $data['item'];
       }
}
```

or

```
  if(isset($contents['23'][0]['item'])){

     //if array 23 exists do something here.
     $result = $data['item'];
  }
```

As I used to always go for `foreach`, I need to know what is the most reliable and fastest way?

Which method should use to filter search results?

Comment: Reliable? Foreach loop. Fastest? If statements (pending length of array) I would assume. Set time() before and after both and time() after, then see for yourself which one is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't think which of this two is faster, `if` or `foreach`. It's called premature optimization and it's probably the worst you can do.
By choosing faster of this two, you'll get no more than 0.05ms (probably even less) and you just lost so much time to ask that question and think about that "problem".

Unless it's critical part of your code (and it's not! You're connecting to database, it just took much more time than all your `if`s and `foreach`es), don't touch it.

Answer (score -1):

I think second one is more faster because there is no need to looping. loop takes more time to execute a command.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).